# Show that all trajectory of the system $\frac{dY}{dt}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 4 \\ -9 & 0 \end{pmatrix}Y$ is an ellipse

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that all trajectory of the system $\frac{dY}{dt}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 4 \\ -9 & 0 \end{pmatrix}Y$

I allready got the particular trajectorys but I'm have been strugguling with the demostration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
x' &= 4y \\ y' &= -9 x
\end{align}$$
$$\dfrac {dx}{dy}=\dfrac {4y}{-9x}$$
$$-9xdx=4ydy$$
Integrate:
$$-9x^2=4y^2+K$$
$$\dfrac {x^2}{4}+\dfrac {y^2}{9}=C$$
These  are ellipses.

Comment: This one is the answer

Comment: Thank you @lev ...

Answer (score 1):

Your system is equivalent to
\begin{align}
x' &= 4y \\ y' &= -9 x
\end{align}
Differentiate a second time these equations : you obtain two separate differential equations of order 2, the first in $x$, the second in $y$. The solutions can be expressed in terms of $\cos$ and $\sin$.